# spring boot @transactional not rolling back upon exception, claiming Winning rollback rule is: RollbackRuleAttribute with pattern

Tags: spring-boot, exception, transactions, rollback

After reading much SO material and googling any possible avenue, I turn to your help:

I have a public method in a @service class which commits a few transactions through the @repository.  Although I declared the transaction to rollback upon the Exception (and tried also covering more general classes such as Runtime Exception, Throwable etc.), it does not roll back, rather stays committed in the DB even after throwing the aforementioned exception.
Upon logging the transactions on log level, these are the lines I get:

```
Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.updateCategoryOrder]
2020-01-01 14:22:40.795 TRACE 1580 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$DefaultCrudMethodMetadata@66a50c93] for key [public abstract void com.aliza.davening.repositories.CategoryRepository.updateCategoryOrder(int,long)] from thread [main]
2020-01-01 14:22:40.795 TRACE 1580 --- [           main] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [com.aliza.davening.services.AdminService.changeCategoryOrder] after exception: exceptions.ReorderCategoriesException: Now everything should stay the same.
2020-01-01 14:22:40.795 TRACE 1580 --- [           main] o.s.t.i.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute    : Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback on exceptions.ReorderCategoriesException: Now everything should stay the same.
2020-01-01 14:22:40.795 TRACE 1580 --- [           main] o.s.t.i.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute    : 
**Winning rollback rule is: RollbackRuleAttribute with pattern [exceptions.ReorderCategoriesException]**
2020-01-01 14:22:40.795 TRACE 1580 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Clearing transaction synchronization
2020-01-01 14:22:40.795 TRACE 1580 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@6442cf3e] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@7e1fb22c] from thread [main]
2020-01-01 14:22:40.795 TRACE 1580 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@7b4c793b] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] from thread [main]
Exception in thread "main" exceptions.ReorderCategoriesException: Now everything should stay the same.
```

It seems from the log that he does look into the option of rolling back, and just gets stuck on assessing if the rule I provided is enough.
Does the 'winning rule' I bolded mean he concluded to roll back?  If so, why are the transactions committed?

Alternatively, if the 'winning rule' means he concluded that the rule I provided is not enough to rollback, how can I make this rollback rule work?

Here is the code:

```java
    @Service("adminService")
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = ReorderCategoriesException.class)
    public class AdminService {

            public void changeCategoryOrder() 
                throws ReorderCategoriesException {

                //updateCategoryOrder accepts the order and id of a category
                categoryRepository.updateCategoryOrder(1, 4);
                categoryRepository.updateCategoryOrder(2,11);
                categoryRepository.updateCategoryOrder(3, 9);

                //this exception should in theory cause the previous commits to rollback, I would think?
                throw new ReorderCategoriesException("Now everything should stay the same.");

        }
    }
```

Here is the repository class performing the DB actions:

```java
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("update Category set catOrder=?1 where id=?2")
        public void updateCategoryOrder(int newOrder, long categoryId);
}
```

The exception is defined as so: (I tried inheriting from Exception and from RuntimeException, same result)

```java
    package exceptions;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class ReorderCategoriesException extends RuntimeException {

        public ReorderCategoriesException(String msg) {
            super(msg);
        }
    }
```

And finally, this is how I call the method from the main:

```java
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    public class MyApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws ReorderCategoriesException {

            ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);

            AdminService adminService = context.getBean(AdminService.class);

            adminService.changeCategoryOrder();
}
```

The pom.xml file (which includes the spring-boot-autoconfigure dependency) is below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.my-project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>project-name</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any help or insight would appreciated to get the DB actions rolled back upon the exception thrown.

Comment: Please share the pom.xml , also you need to specify @EnableTransactionManagement annotation. It's on by default. Specify spring-boot-autoconfigure.jar as dependency and try.

Comment: Can you try implementing your custom exception extending ```org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException``` instead of ```RuntimeException```? Not sure if it will work but it's possible that the issue may stem from having only one constructor for your custom exception - ```Throwable``` also has a constructor that takes both a ```String``` message and a ```Throwable``` cause.

Comment: @ChristianMeyer, tried that but didn't help.

Comment: @dassum I did specify the annotation in both the service class and the main class (just to be sure... because I didn't know where it is supposed to go.  Didn't help anyway). I added the dependency in the pom.xml file (still not working), and I'm posting it in the question.